# Chart legend labels do not appear when creating from a pivot table using the app script

Tags: charts, google-apps-script

I'm trying to build a chart from a pivot table that I created using the following code:

```
   var requests = [{
    "updateCells": {
      "rows": {
        "values": [{
            "pivotTable": {
              "source": {
                "sheetId": firstSheetId,
                "startRowIndex": 0,
                "startColumnIndex": 0,
                "endRowIndex": ranges.length,
                "endColumnIndex": question.length + 3
              },
              "rows": [{
                  "sourceColumnOffset": 2,
                  "showTotals": false,
                  "sortOrder": "ASCENDING",
                  "valueBucket": {
                    "buckets": [
                      {
                        "stringValue": question[i-3]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "columns": [
                {
                  "sourceColumnOffset": i,
                  "sortOrder": "ASCENDING",
                  "showTotals": false
                }
              ],
              "values": [
                {
                  "summarizeFunction": "COUNTA",
                  "sourceColumnOffset": i
                }
              ],
              "valueLayout": "HORIZONTAL"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "start": {
        "sheetId": fourthSheetId,
        "rowIndex": index,
        "columnIndex": 0
      },
      "fields": "pivotTable"
    }
  }
  ];

  var batchUpdateRequest = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
  batchUpdateRequest.requests = requests;

  // Add additional requests (operations)
  var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(batchUpdateRequest, ss.getId());
```

Then, I'm trying to use the created pivot table to make a chart using the following code, but the chart legend labels do not appear in the chart.  However, when selecting the pivot table by the mouse and clicking the "Insert -> Chart" from the Google Spreadsheet menu, the labels appear fine.

```
    var textStyleBuilder = Charts.newTextStyle().setColor('#0000FF');
var style = textStyleBuilder.build();

for (i = 0; i < tableDim.length; i++) {
  /* Get pivot table dimensions */
  var sRow        = (tableDim[i].startRow);
  var nRow        = (tableDim[i].endRow - tableDim[i].startRow);
  var sCol        = (tableDim[i].startCol);
  var nCol        = (tableDim[i].endCol - tableDim[i].startCol);

  secondSheet.showSheet();

  var currentRange = secondSheet.getDataRange().offset(sRow, sCol, nRow, nCol );

  /* Build the chart */
  var chart = secondSheet.newChart()
   .asBarChart()
   .setStacked()
   .setLegendTextStyle(style)
   .setLegendPosition(Charts.Position.RIGHT)
   .addRange(currentRange)
   .setXAxisTitle("Values")
   .setYAxisTitle("Names")
   .setPosition(sRow, nCol + sCol + 1, nRow + sRow, 2*(nCol + sCol))
   .setOption("title", question[i])
   .build();

  secondSheet.insertChart(chart);

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

This is my current chart, where the label text doesn't appear:

[image: Label text doesn't appear]

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem where I had an off-by-one error in the data range offset.

```
var currentRange = secondSheet.getDataRange().offset(sRow - 1 , sCol, nRow, nCol );
```

Once I added the "**- 1**" to the **sRow** value, the correct data labels were shown in the chart.